# Can't get JSON data to display in jtemplate in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, jtemplates

I'm doing very basic stuff here using jQuery, JSON data coming back, trying to display it using jTemplates on an aspx page. All my code is straight copy paste from examples I've googled. No original code. I've been able to debug to the point where I see the result.d data back from my web svc is JSON data.

```
{"MG":{"Status":"Pending",...
```

My template is:

```
<script type="text/html" id="TemplateResultsTable">
{#template MAIN}
 <table  cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>{$T.MG.Status}</td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>Price</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 {#/template MAIN}  
</script>
```

My jquery code to setup the template is:

```
$('#InnerResult').setTemplate($('#TemplateResultsTable').html());
$('#InnerResult').processTemplate(result.d);
```

And I have a div (panel actually) id'd as InnerResult.

The table in the template displays just fine so I know that part is working. It's just that the data $T.MG.Status refuses to display. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks. I totally missed that. I almost always get great info and plenty of answers on SO. What if the answer is in a comment? Doesn't seem to be a way to mark the comment as an answer.

Comment: Comment on that and ask him to put this comment as an Answer..

Comment: Thanks. Any idea about an answer to my current question?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out after losing more hair! Not one of the thousand ASP.NET, JSON examples I saw mentioned that you can't use the JSON data in the form of a string. You have to do something like:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(result.d);
```

Now I can easily reference {$T.MG.Status}.